# $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m \mathbb{Z}} \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong 0$ is an application of general property about tensor products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I had an exercise where I had to proof that $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m \mathbb{Z}} \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong 0$. I could do this using the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3047612/340973) but I was wondering if the fact that $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m \mathbb{Z}} \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong 0$ could be deduced as a more general result about tensor products.

Comment: the accepted answer in the thread you linked doesn't use any result. Just look at the proof, it is self contained. The general fact is that $\mathbb Q$ has no torsion and every element of $\mathbb Z_m$ is an $m$-torsion element so the tensor product is $0$.

Comment: I think it comes down to roughly the same argument. Given some $\Bbb Z$-bilinear map of $\Bbb Z$-modules $f : \Bbb Z / m \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Q \to A$ you have $f(x,y) = f(x,y \cdot m/m) = f(mx,y/m) = f(0,y/m) = 0$.

Comment: Maybe the result $\frac{R}{I} \otimes M \cong \frac{M}{IM}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Consider the short exact sequence:
$$0\longrightarrow \mathbf Z \xrightarrow{\,\times m\:} \mathbf Z \longrightarrow  \mathbf Z /m \mathbf Z \longrightarrow 0 $$
and tensor it with the *flat* $\mathbf Z$-module $\mathbf Q$, to obtain the short exact sequence:
$$0\longrightarrow \mathbf Q \xrightarrow{\,\times m\enspace} \mathbf Q \longrightarrow  \mathbf Z /m \mathbf Z\otimes_{\mathbf Z} \mathbf Q \longrightarrow 0, $$
in which the  homomorphism of multiplication by $m$ is now an *isomorphism* since $ \mathbf Q $ is a field.

Answer (score 6):

If $G$ is an abelian group such that each of its elements has finite order, then $G\otimes\mathbb Q=\{0\}$. In fact, if $g\in G$ and if $m\in\mathbb N$ is such that $mg=0$, then, for each $q\in\mathbb Q$,$$g\otimes q=g\otimes\left(m\frac qm\right)=(mg)\otimes\frac qm=0\otimes\frac qm=0.$$

Comment: Thank you, I know the question is not very clear. Is there a generalisation for something more general that "looks like $\mathbb{Q}$"?

Comment: Sure: replace $\mathbb Q$ with any [divisible group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group).